# How to make terminal auto-append and prepend quotation marks to pasted texts/links?

Tags: macos, terminal

[Kitty terminal](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty) can paste URLs in and I think by default, it auto-appends and prepends quotation marks. Try something like `yt-dlp [url]`, and kitty by default makes it so that you don't have to put the quotation marks.

How do I replicate this behavior on another terminal emulator such as the stock Mac terminal?